# Detect if first auth via Facebook/Google

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth with the Facebook & Google login. After a successful login, I also register the user on my own server.

```
// facebook or google auth   
firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            registerOnServer(task);
        }
    });
```

That works fine the first time. But the second time the user logs in, my backend complains, because a user with those credentials already exists.

**How can I detect if this is the first time a user logs in via one of the given providers?** I can't use SharedPreferes, because they get erased after a user uninstalls the app, which leads to problems after reinstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
firebaseAuth.fetchProvidersForEmail(userEmail).
addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ProviderQueryResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ProviderQueryResult> task) {
        List<String> providerList = task.getResult().getProviders();
            if (providerList.isEmpty()) {
                //Empty List means new user
            }
            else if (providerList.contains("facebook.com")) {
               //Facebook is the provider
            }
   }
}
```

Use above code to get providers.